# Using GCD/asynchronous code in drawRect:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to load an image from a url inside of `drawRect:`. Our image-loading code is a method that looks like this: `- (void) loadImage:(NSURL*)url done:(void(^)(UIImage*))done;`, which creates an asynchronous NSURLConnection and calls back with the image.

So, my code in `drawRect:` looks like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
[service loadImage:url done:^(UIImage * image){
    CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image.CGImage);
}];
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The image is never drawn.

I've also tried using synchronous connections (`[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:]`), but it blocks the thread and slows things down unnecessarily. I don't want to use a UIImageView.

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know how you solved this problem, I am stuck with the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct way would either be to load the image beforehand or draw the image as soon as you receive it by either calling "setNeedsDisplayInRect:" or doing your own drawing handling in a separate method (iOS might discourage you from doing this though, I am not sure). Obviously the setNeedsDisplayInRect variation would require you to have the image at hand for drawing the second time around (cache it).

If you load the image asynchronously your drawRect method will moste likely have exited before the image is loaded and the draw focus is no longer locked on your drawRect, thus making it impossible to draw the image in the context. Did you try to set a breakpoint to verify this though? I might be wrong about the locking, but thought I read something alike this at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Think it through--why *would* it run? There's no guarantee that `context` is still the current context (or even that its backing store is still fully valid) by the time the block is entered. By using an asynchronous callback, be it a block or a delegate method or something else, you're intentionally deferring code to a later point in time. The call to `-drawRect:` has ended and is off the stack long before your block is entered.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to make sure the async handler runs on the main thread:

```
[service loadImage:url done:^(UIImage * image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image.CGImage);
    });
}];
```

If that does not help, I would start to wonder if the context is still valid. The pointer is, but the context probably not. Maybe you could move the context acquisition to the handler:

```
[service loadImage:url done:^(UIImage * image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image.CGImage);
        …
    });
}];
```

Not sure if that makes sense API-wise, I don’t do much stuff like this.

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm afraid. Thanks! The other posters were correct that there is no valid context available at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
__block CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
[service loadImage:url done:^(UIImage * image){
    CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image.CGImage);
}];
```

You may have to do the same thing with frame, so when the block returns it knows what context and frame it should modify.